# Iterate through registry folders with Qt

Tags: qt, registry, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I need to list the devices in the HID Bluetooth LE (BTHLE) folder of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\` directory. By using

```
#define REG_PATH "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\BTHLE"    
QSettings settings(REG_PATH, QSettings::NativeFormat);
QStringList regReturn = settings.allKeys();
```

I can get to all folders and subfolders of the path, but I need to scan through the folders, find those devices with a given PID and VID and a given value of the registrykey `FriendlyName` to identify my device(s).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain content of a particular sub folder, you can do the following (I used another example, because I don't know the structure of the BTHLE directory):

```
[..]
// Get the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_045E&PID_00B4\5&1b6962&0&1\Class key
const QString top("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\USB");
const QString device("VID_045E&PID_00B4");

QSettings settings(top, QSettings::NativeFormat);
settings.beginGroup(device); // Limit keys by this device only.
QStringList regReturn = settings.allKeys();
QString vStr = regReturn[1]; // 5&1b6962&0&1/Class

QString v = settings.value(regReturn[1]).toString(); // returns "USB"
```

Comment: Using your path and exact example, regReturn doesn't provide anything. and is completely empty. Have you tested this yourself?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen, sure, it works on my computer, but not necesserely will on yours. The given example was made to demonstrate how to use QSettings API. You have to adjust it to your environment.

Comment: I am truly sorry, it works like a charm. I misspelled the VID parameter of the device. Thank you! I also see how the strings in the returned list are formatted now and see how easy it actually is. Great!